# Watch movies remotely with a friend

Tags: video, remote-access, streaming, screen-sharing

#### Task I want to accomplish

My friend lives in another country and has a bunch of movies on his computer in the form of MP4 files.

I want to be able to watch those movies with him.

#### My requirements

I need to be able to see his screen and hear the sound of the movie.

It would also be an added bonus if I could talk to him while the movie is on too.

#### What I already know

I know about a program called TeamViewer but there are many security issues surrounding that program at the moment and I would prefer to use something else.

I also know about a website called rabb.it but you can only watch movies using Netflix together.

Comment: Just curious....the video quality and sound quality via Team Viewer is okay?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow It's not ideal but it's watchable for me. I don't know your standards though :)

Comment: I've added a small list of options for you, hope it gives you a few options to try!

Comment: My friend and I used to do this all the time. We'd use Skype to transfer the video file and then start a call. We'd both open the file, I'd count down "5... 4... 3... 2... 1!" and we'd both hit play at the same time. Low-tech, but always worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your requirements, there are a few options I could provide you. Please be aware I've used all the below options, but not to screen share music and movies, so these may all fail to meet your requirements. You can read up on most of below here on [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Another-Computer-from-Your-Computer).

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en)  - I do not have much detail on the security of the application, however I know it supports sound and screen sharing. (Note for chat on the PC I could not think of a way to natively incorporate it with this scenario).

[Remote Utilities](https://www.remoteutilities.com/download/) - allows you to remote into the PC in a "view only" session and also has the ability to use the "chat" feature of the program. I've personally found this works quite well, and supports live chat and remote access - you'll need to look into the security yourself however.

[Using Hamachi](http://www.howtogeek.com/131961/how-to-access-windows-remote-desktop-over-the-internet/) + `mstsc.exe`: I cannot say I have personally used this for your purpose, but it is another valid option for you and your friend! (You'll need port forwarding for this one).

[TightVNC](http://www.howtogeek.com/124849/how-to-remote-control-your-home-computer-from-anywhere-with-vnc/) -  I am not too sure if this allows you to natively hear the music/movie (from *memory* it does, but don't trust me on this).

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off sharing the playback stream [using VLC](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-privately-stream-video-with-vlc-for-windows/) or another media player. You could use a separate channel to talk.